# fsockopen or exec(telnet 10.64.109.111) doesn't go to login prompt

Tags: php, telnet

direct telnet on the linux machine goes up to login: prompt. If I try to login in to switch by
PHP exec('telnet 10.64.109.111') or fsockopen it stopped at the point

Escape character is '^]'.

While regular telnet on the console goes up to login: prompt

Escape character is '^]'.

login:

Note sure what is the solution here.
Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `fsockopen` - it has examples of telnet connections in the comments - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: Connection is successful, fsockopen doesn't return false. Problem is that it doesn't go to the correct prompt.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280257/how-do-i-use-fsockopen-to-open-a-telnet-connection-with-a-password

Comment: I'm wondering, why you are using exec and telnet, it sounds very  unsecure ;-)

Comment: yeah exec is bad but first I tried with fsockopen and then to root cause the problem I used exec.

Comment: It sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) ;-)

Comment: this is not XY problem.

Comment: 1. `exec()` won't work because you can't send more input to the program. 2. Show us some flippin **code**.

Comment: Can you share what your goal is? Get data from a server via PHP? I'm just wondering if you're taking a difficult path to this goal ;-)

Comment: telnet to the Brocade switch and fire some commands.

Comment: I suggest that you include that info in your question - you might then get better answers/responses ...