# PHP connect to Telnet server

Tags: php, telnet

I need to connect to a Server and send Commands VIA Telnet but am having a bit of trouble finding out how to connect with authorization.

I have used the following script to connect, but I still need to input username and password to gain access.

```
<?php

          $host="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
    $port = xxxxxxxxxx; // open a client connection 
    $fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr); 
    if (!$fp) { 
    $result = "Error: could not open socket connection"; 
    } 
    else { // get the welcome message fgets ($fp, 1024); // write the user string to the socket 
    fputs($fp, $message); // get the result $result .= fgets ($fp, 1024); // close the connection
    fputs ($fp, "END");
    fclose ($fp); // trim the result and remove the starting ?
    $result = trim($result);
    $result = substr($result, 2); // now print it to the browser 
    } ?> 
    Server said: <? echo $result; ?>


    ?>
```

Ive been looking around, even on the PHP documentation but don't see a way to use password and username.

Do I have to use POST data to post my username and password?

Comment: The TELNET protocol RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854

Comment: Do you need to wait a moment for the prompt to come up before you enter it? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6280342/5947043. P.S. What do you mean by POST data? That's a HTTP concept as far as I know, not telnet. Of course you can use a telnet connection to send HTTP commands if the listener on the socket is a HTTP server, but that's a whole other story. You didn't mention what service you're connecting to or what kind of commands you were looking to send

Comment: @ADyson Its a VPS  I run with a Game server. the Game server uses Telnet.

Comment: Telnet just opens a TCP connection. After that you must be using some specific protocol to exchange messages? There is a basic telnet protocol for simple messages but you can't do much. There is presumably some further agreed format using which the messages are constructed.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said already, telnet just opens a socket to a server.  This is what your call to fsockopen() is doing as well.  The service you're connecting to should have a definition for what you can do next.

Assume a connection to an FTP server.  Once the connection has been established, you can write the LIST command to the socket.  The server will recognize that command and send a file listing back to your socket.

In your case, your exchange might be something like:

```
write:  AUTH
read:   OK
write:  USERNAME username
read:   OK
write   PASSWORD password
read:   STATUS OK
```

Comment: So what I would need to do essentially is write a script to connect, then an if statement with the bit you shared up top? As for the definition of what to do next, im not sure how to find that out. Im using my own VPS and game server.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what you're doing, I'd imagine you need to implement the parts that read from and write data to the server you're connecting to.  This is usually detailed in a specification of some sort.

Comment: How would I go about with PHP reading for the line "Please enter password" ? That I believe is where I am hung up

Comment: I'd imagine you would use something like socket_read() to read data from the server.  You'll probably continue reading until you see a line terminator.  Perhaps it will be a newline (\n).  If all of this is applicable, then you would compare what you just read in to see if it is "Please enter password."  Other than this, I'm afraid the details about this environment are too vague to be of much more help.